# Multiply cell, in a dataframe, by a constant if cell value is less than a specified value

Tags: python

**Multiply cell, in a dataframe, by a constant if cell value is less than a specified value.**

Wanting to do something like below. Where the true causes the multiplication to happen and re-assigns the new value to the cell in the dataframe. The false should leave the value alone. But this gives and error and other things I've seen online are not working:

```
if  df['value'] < 50:
    df['value']=df['value']*(1*10^5)
else:
    df['value']=df['value']


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have also tried:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: [y if y<=50 for y in x])
```

But I think my syntax is wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: is your else statement correct in the first part? are you planning to update `df['price']`

Comment: In that part: if the else statement is executed, then that value should be re-assigned to 'value' or just left alone. For that else, no, df['value'] doesn't technically need to be updated. Thanks good catch.

Comment: see if this works `df.loc[df['value'] < 50, 'value'] = df['value']*(1*10^5)`

Comment: can you please post sample data from your dataframe. This works only if the column `value` is numeric. it will not work if it is a string or some other datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the result.

```
df.loc[df['value'] < 50, 'value'] = df['value']*(1*10**5)
```

More documentation of IF condition can be found [here](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/)

If you want to use the lambda function, you can do something like this.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x*(1*10**5) if x < 50 else x)
```

Agree with @Grzegorz Skibinski. This is a better option:

```
df.loc[df['value'] < 50, 'value'] *= 10**5
```

Comment: I tried and got error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Which is strange because 'value' is of type float

Comment: share a copy of your DataFrame so I can help you

Comment: lambda function works: df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x*(1*10^5) if x < 50 else x) but doesn't give the correct resulting value if I wanted to multiply the cell by 1*10^5

Comment: sorry about that, it should be `lambda x: x*(1*10**5)` not ^

Comment: Great. If this solved your problem you may want to read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: `apply()` is probably the slowest option here, how about: `df.loc[df['value'] < 50, 'value'] *= 10^5`?